# VS2010: Function time() not as expected

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, time

Consider the following small program:

```
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t now;
    now = time(NULL); // This term gives an error in VS2010

    return 0;
}
```

On Ubuntu with `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0` this compiles without errors.

When I use above code snippet inside a VS2010 project, though, the project does not build. The error is:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

I have also tried to use `time()` and `time(&time_t)`. Both fail with `error C2064`. According to [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33(v=vs.100).aspx) above usage *should* be correct.

How many arguments does the `time()` function actually take in VS2010?

Comment: Compile with MSVC 2015 without error.

Comment: @Stargateur: No, there's no "by default" in MSVC. MSVC's behavior is pretty much the same as any other compiler's behavior: the language depends on the file extension or can be specified manually.

Comment: Do you have a user defined time(...) function?

Comment: When you say "I use above code snippet inside a VS2010 project" do you mean a *larger* project with other code as well? Or do you mean the same small program by itself?

Comment: @RustyX `time(nullptr)` also fails.

Comment: @AnT Oh indeed never mind, I read it somewhere but never tested.

Comment: @RustyX `nullptr` is a keyword cpp don't use it with a c function because it's probably UB.

Comment: @Stargateur how would that affect the build? I use, in fact, `time(NULL)`  inside a C++ project. However, there are other C functions used without a problem. Additionally, AFAIK, C++ is supposed to be able to handle C.

Comment: @nautical: If you have other code in your VS project, then the reason is in that other code. You must have redeclared `time` somehow. The above small program compiles fine in VS. (And no, C is not a subset of C++. It is a different language. So in general case C++ is not supposed to be able "to handle C").

Comment: The code by itself as shown is fine. I would check library paths, global definitions and the VS installation itself.

Comment: You say *"When I use above code snippet inside a VS2010 project..."* So it's not that code you posted which gives the problem, but code you didn't post?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, the project is too large to post. It is only the single commented line that causes the problem. If I comment it out in the VS project everything is fine. So there is probably another function already included which conflicts.

Comment: try this     (::time)(NULL)

Comment: @user3853544 Thank you. This worked. Could you post this as an answer? I think this fix should get more exposure.

Comment: Did you really compile your [mcve] and did you just reduce your complex code to the minimum without testing it still shows the problem? BTW, I'ld expect you need to `#include <stddef.h>` for `NULL`.

Comment: @nautical: Yours is rather mundane beginner's error, which has very extensive exposure here. (Unfortunately such errors are not very "searchable"). Also, since your code appears to be C++, it would be more appropriate to include `<ctime>` instead of `<time.h>` and use the function as `std::time`. Finally, if you provided more context, maybe we'd be able to find a more elegant solution than calling `::time`.

Comment: It all boils down to: does **this snippet** compile successful or not? You did not make this clear, nor specify the exact problem and location. If not, you have to check your toolchain, because this is valid code, although bad style using the C headers in a C++ project, Otherwise the problem is apparently in the other code.

Comment: @WernerHenze: `NULL` is defined in multiple files. Additional ther can be indirect includes. But you are right, it is strongly advised to include all headers needed.

Comment: @AnT It was, in fact, a trivial error. The error message was very misleading, though. Added an answer with more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work but you should figure out what the conflict is... This is a hack.

```
(::time)(NULL)
```

EDIT: New information from op. This was the original code:

```
time_t time = 0;
time_t now;
now = time(NULL);
```

Conflict in variable name solution is this:

```
time_t myTime = 0;
time_t now;
now = time(NULL);
```

Comment: Found the conflict and added it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the actual error. This is not originally my project but I recently got to work on it to add some functionality.

As it turns out the error was quite trivial. After going thoroughly through the source code again I noticed that a variable `time_t time;` had already been declared. When I tried to assign `now = time(NULL);` the aforementioned variable interfered with the function call.

The error message `term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments` from VS2010 is quite distracting in this case. If the argument were omitted it would change to `term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments`. From this messages I assumed that either another function named `time()` from another included file got called or that VS2010 has a non-standard implementation of `time()`.

Calling the function - as suggested in the comments by user3853544 - with `now = (::time)(NULL);` signalled the compiler that I am refering to a function instead of the previously declared variable. Another solution can be to rename the offending variable so that it does not collide with a function name.

**PS**: I recreated the problem and tried to compile it on Ubuntu. The error message from `gcc` is a lot more informative and precise:

```
$ cat sample.c
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t time = 0;
    time_t now;
    now = time(NULL);

    return 0;
}
$
$ gcc sample.c 
sample.c: In function ‘main’:
sample.c:6:8: error: called object ‘time’ is not a function or function pointer
  now = time(NULL);
        ^
sample.c:4:9: note: declared here
  time_t time = 0;
         ^
```

Comment: And that is why you should paste your original code :)

Comment: My VS2013 flags this as an error I'm surprised yours didn't catch it

Comment: @user3853544 Well, the original code was too big to paste. The error message send me down the wrong path. If the project had been compiled with gcc the issue would have been fixed within seconds :-)

Comment: InteliSence:  Error expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type. Underlines the attempted call on time with red.  Compiler: Outputs error C2665: 'time' none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types.

Comment: @user3853544 This is a bit more precise than what VS2010 gives me (`error C2064: term does not ...`).